# Cannot install pytorch in a virtualenv on windows

Tags: python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, pytorch

I know there are a few topics about that on this website but still, I can't find the solution.

So here is what I did : 
I created a projecton Visual Studio 19 for python.
I added an virtual environment with Python 3.7 using the file requirements.txt

It contains

```
mypy==0.750
pylint==2.4.4
pytest==5.3.1
matplotlib==3.1.1
torch==1.3.1
tensorflow==2.1.0rc0
```

This requirement file works perfectly well on linux. But on vs19 I get the following :

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.3.1 (from -r E:\Documents\Blub\Granolar\requirements.txt (line 5)) (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)`
```

Since I don't want to downgrade to 0.1.2 (obviously) how can I fix it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with your exact environment but it's possible pip isnt up to date. In your virtualenv can you try running `pip install --upgrade pip`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went to the [*PyTorch* documentation on how to "Start Locally"](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) and selected what seems to be your environment:

- PyTorch Build: Stable (1.3)
- Your OS: Windows
- Package: Pip
- Language: Python 3.7
- CUDA: None

The resulting instruction I got back as a result is:

```
pip3 install torch==1.3.1+cpu torchvision==0.4.2+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

So most likely you could modify your `requirements.txt` like this:

```
mypy==0.750
pylint==2.4.4
pytest==5.3.1
matplotlib==3.1.1
torch==1.3.1+cpu --find-links https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
tensorflow==2.1.0rc0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
`pip install -r requirements.txt` gave me the same error. The above suggest of including the link inside requirements.txt didn't work for me either.

What did work for me was manually entering

```
pip install torch===1.3.1 torchvision===0.4.2 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

in command line.